# Can we forecast the Trend component of a decomposed time series?

Tags: time-series, trend

I am looking to forecasting the decomposed trend component of a time series.

What would be the right way to go about it?

Comment: You can try some experiments with Prophet https://github.com/facebook/prophet

Comment: What kind of trend are you looking at? A "global" one, or a "local" one, e.g., like what an STL decomposition returns?